Inconsistent vertical spacing of column headings in table when using \multicolumn
I have a standard table with two multicolumns in the column headings, but this causes odd vertical spacing shown in the diagram by the orange arrows. What am I doing wrong?
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \caption{A caption}
    {\tiny
    \label{table:label}
    \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{1.2cm}p{0.75cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.75cm}p{0.5cm}}
    \hline \\[-1.5ex]

Occupancy Category  &   \multicolumn{2}{l}{\parbox{1.5cm}{Breathing rate, $Q_b$ (m$^{3}$\,h$^{-1}$)}} & Respiratory activity, \textit{breathing: \newline talking: \newline vocalizing} (\%) & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\parbox{2.2cm}{Respiratory particle concentration in exhaled air, $C_{drop}$ (respiratory particles\,m$^{-3}$)}} &    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\parbox{1.5cm}{Mean respiratory particle diameter, $\overline{d}$ (m)}}\\    

    &   GM  &   GSD &       &   GM ($\times 10^4$)  &   GSD &   GM ($\times 10^{-6}$)   &   GSD \\
    \\[-1.5ex] \hline \\[-1.5ex]
Some information    &   A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\  [1.5ex]
\hline
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}



Welcome on TeX StackExchange!

You should provide a full compilable code, with the \documentclass, the \begin{document}, etc.

You should use \parbox[t] instead of \parbox.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \caption{A caption}
    {\tiny
    \label{table:label}
    \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{1.2cm}p{0.75cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.75cm}p{0.5cm}}
    \hline \\[-1.5ex]
Occupancy Category  &   \multicolumn{2}{l}{\parbox[t]{1.5cm}{Breathing rate, $Q_b$ (m$^{3}$\,h$^{-1}$)}} & Respiratory activity, \textit{breathing: \newline talking: \newline vocalizing} (\%) & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\parbox[t]{2.2cm}{Respiratory particle concentration in exhaled air, $C_{drop}$ (respiratory particles\,m$^{-3}$)}} &    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\parbox[t]{1.5cm}{Mean respiratory particle diameter, $\overline{d}$ (m)}}\\    

    &   GM  &   GSD &       &   GM ($\times 10^4$)  &   GSD &   GM ($\times 10^{-6}$)   &   GSD \\
    \\[-1.5ex] \hline \\[-1.5ex]
Some information    &   A   &   B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F   &   G   \\  [1.5ex]
\hline
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}


